# Trying to find an old Scifi short story for kids. Boy & Father travel to another planet alone after rest of the ships crew goes insane

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, young-adult

Read it in the early 80's but felt like it was from the 70's or 60's. School library collection of sci-fi stories for elementary school kids (multi-volume series was blue hardbacks I think). The one story I remember from the series is a boy and father traveling from earth to a neighboring planet that had contacted humanity and taking place after several years voyage with the crew one by one going crazy from 'space sickness' and the father dumping them out the airlock. Father may have been captain or security chief. Then right before the ship arrives at their destination the father starts to go crazy as well. Benevolent telepathic natives from the planet intervene and save the boy (who is also telepathic) from his father and begin the healing process for the father. Maybe 30 pages tops.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Sci-Fi Stackexchange! This is a great and very interesting question. I hope someone comes along soon to answer it. While you wait, feel free to checkout the [tour] and have a look at the [help]!